# Java - URLConnection Inquiry

Tags: java, urlconnection

As the title states, I'm attempting to simply send a HTTP request to a webserver with URLConnection, but when I attempt to run the script, it does not send the request, nor does it give me an error.

Code:

```
public static URLConnection connection;
new URL("http://website.com/dostuff.php?whatever=" + whatever).openConnection();
```

Comment: The request might not actually be sent until you try to access the status code or streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL.openConnection` does not create the connection immediately. It only connects after you call a method that requires a connection. For example:

```
URL url = ...;
InputStream in = url.openStream(); // connection happens here
// you can now read the output from in
```

Comment: I just tried openConnection().connect(); and it still did not throw an error or work.

Comment: Then try `openConnection().getInputStream()` and discard the result. Alternatively, use `openStream()` for less code, it does the same thing.

Comment: Can I get a code snippet to help me out? I'm new with this function =[

Comment: I posted a code snippet in the answer. That assumes you also want the output of the script